# How can remove import directives from JS file when compiling TS to JS in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

The problem is how automatically can remove import directives from JavaScript file when compiling TS to JS or advise me a solution how to organize work with packages downloaded from npm in Visual Studio 2019.

I developing web application in Visual Studio 2019 using ASP.NET Core and MSBuild for compiling TS to JS. I create a TypeScript file, import two npm packages into it: jQuery and Axios, then compiling TS to JS, and, through the Gulp task manager, I copy libraries from the node_modules folder to the wwwroot folder.

In the end, I have four files: htmldom.ts (a TypeScript source code that contains code using jQuery and Axios); compiled htmldom.js; and libraries from the npm repository (jquery.js and axios.js)
This is what how TS file looks like:

```
import "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js";
import "../node_modules/@types/jquery/index";
import axios from "../node_modules/axios/index"

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        $("#button").on("click", function () {
            alert("hello jquery!!!");
        });

        var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
        var data = axios.get(url).then(function (responce) {
            console.log(responce.data);
        });
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Here's what how the compiled JS file looks like:

```
import "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js";
import "../node_modules/@types/jquery/index";
import axios from "../node_modules/axios/index";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        $("#button").on("click", function () {
            alert("hello jquery!!!");
        });
        var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
        var data = axios.get(url).then(function (responce) {
            console.log(responce.data);
        });
        console.log(data);
    });
});
//# sourceMappingURL=htmldom.js.map
```

This is what how MVC View looks like with libraries:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="click me" />
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="~/javascripts/jquery.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/javascripts/axios.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/compiled/htmldom.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

When I placing the compiled JS file with libraries into the view, the JS does not work and gives an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected string

When I remove the import directives from the JS file everything works fine:

```
//import "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js";
//import "../node_modules/@types/jquery/index";
//import axios from "../node_modules/axios/index";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        $("#button").on("click", function () {
            alert("hello jquery!!!");
        });
        var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
        var data = axios.get(url).then(function (responce) {
            console.log(responce.data);
        });
        console.log(data);
    });
});
//# sourceMappingURL=htmldom.js.map
```

The problem is how automatically can remove import directives from JavaScript file when compiling TS to JS or advise me how to use third-party libraries using TypeScript in Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I write an extension that delete import directives

```
    public static class ApplicationBuilderExtension
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseRemoveImport(this IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var path = env.WebRootPath + "/assets/compiled";

            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.js"))
            {
                var contents = File.ReadAllLines(file);
                var allExceptImport = contents.Where(l => !l.StartsWith("import"));
                File.WriteAllLines(file, allExceptImport);
            }

            return app;
        }
    }
```

and then in startup

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRemoveImport(env);
    app.UseStaticFiles();

}
```